# Send a CSV file from Ember Js to Rails using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ember.js

I'm trying to upload a csv file with ajax from Ember Js and read it in my Rails application. 
I've tried two different approaches. In the first one I tried to send the file from Ember like this:

```
submitImport() {
  var fd = new FormData();
  var file = this.get('files')[0];
  fd.append("csv_file", file);
  return this.get('authAjax')
    .request('/contacts/import/csv', {
      method: 'POST',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data: fd 
    });
}
```

but the problem is that I don't get the csv_file param in the rails application. The request.content_type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and I need multipart form. I could use reques.raw_post but then I get something like this `------WebKitFormBoundarymgBynUffnPTUPW3l\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"csv_file\"; filename=\"elevatr_import.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n\r\ngeorgica,gica@me.com\nleo, leonard@yahoo.com\ngigel, becali@oita.fcsb\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarymgBynUffnPTUPW3l--\r\n` and I would need to somehow parse this, and I don't really like this solution.

The other approach was to send the file base64 encoded and then decode it from Rails. I've tried this:

`

```
submitImport() {
  var fd = new FormData();
  var file = this.get('files')[0];
  this.send('getBase64', file);
  var encoded_file = this.get('encoded_file');

  return this.get('authAjax')
    .request('/contacts/import/csv', {
      method: 'POST',
      data: { csv_file: encoded_file }
    });
},
getBase64(file) {
  var controller = this;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function () {
    controller.set('encoded_file', reader.result);
  };
}
```

But for some reason, the post request is submitted first and only after that the getBase64 method is called.
Does anyone knows why is this happening or if I should use a different approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FormData**

To send using `multipart/form-data`, you have the right idea and are setting the correct options, but it's possible that `authAjax` or something else is setting options that are causing a conflict, resulting in a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
// this should make a request with a content-type of multipart/form-data
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload/destination',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formDataObj,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
});
```

**Base64**

The reason your file is read after your request is made is that `FileReader` works asynchronously. To send as a base64 encoded string, you'll need to wait for the reader to complete before initiating your ajax request. You can do that by making your request after the `onloadend` event.

```
actions: {
  submitImport() {
    var file = this.get('files')[0];
    this.encodeAndSendFile(file);
  },
},
sendFile(base64File) {
  return this.get('authAjax')
  .request('/contacts/import/csv', {
    method: 'POST',
    data: { csv_file: encoded_file },
  });
},
encodeAndSend(file) {
  var controller = this;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function () {
    controller.sendFile(reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was indeed able to encode and send the file using your code. I will also take a look at the `authAjax` service, maybe I will be able to figure this out.